# Django Rest Framework: How to add Rest API End point for a Nested Models[ManyToMany Fields]?

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

I have two models `Patient` and `Docter`.

```
# models.py
class Docter(models.Model):
    ...

class Patient(models.Model):
    ...
    cared_by = models.ManyToManyField(Docter)
```

Now I've got and `ModelViewSet` that handles the basic CRUD operations for the model `User`.

```
#viewsets.py
class PatientViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows patients to be viewed or edited.
    """

    queryset = Patient.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PatientSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Patient.objects.filter(cared_by__in = [self.request.user])

    # Automatically add to cared by when creating object
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(cared_by = [self.request.user])
```

and I can access this view using the `/users/` endpoint.
Now I want to extend this endpoint to Perform Basic CRUD operations for the `cared_by` field on `Patient` model.

So that `/users/2/docters`becomes another end point.

POST `/users/2/docters/` can do `patientinstance.cared_by.add(docter)`

GET `/users/2/docters/` can return `patientinstance.cared_by.all()`

DELETE `/users/2/docters/5` can do `patientinstance.cared_by.remove(docter)`

But right now the only way I could think of doing this is by adding custom @detail_routes to the `PatientViewSet`. Which looks like a very bad practice and I am repeating lot of code.

So can anyone please guide me on how to do this the right way.

Comment: Dear Darwesh, did my solution helped you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is to work with nested resources. For this, there exists a third-party module called [`drf-nested-routers`](https://github.com/alanjds/drf-nested-routers) that helps you achieve what you want.

In your case, you would have something similar:

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', PatientViewSet, basename='users')

doctors_router = routers.NestedSimpleRouter(router, r'users' lookup='user')
doctors_router.register(r'doctors', DoctorViewSet, base_name='doctors')
```

That will provide you the following routes:

```
/users/
/users/{pk}/
/users/{user_pk}/doctors/
/users/{user_pk}/doctors/{doctor_pk}/
```

Check its documentation for more details.